# Concept of NaN, IND, INF and DEN

Tags: c++

Came across this C++ article on the [**CodeProject**](https://www.codeproject.com/): 
 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/824516/Concept-of-NaN-IND-INF-and-DEN

that tried to explain the concept of how [*Infinity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) & [*NaN*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (and other *"special"* numeric types) are represented in computational arithmetic in C++.

---

It was **clear enough to follow where it showed its "standard representation" of each number** type using standard library code but **where it got a bit confusing was the "non-standard representation"** given out of "academic" interest.

The standard representations looked like this:

```
const double STD_NOT_A_NUMBERD = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

while the non-standard representations looked like this:

```
const unsigned long lnNAN[2] = {0x00000000, 0x7ff80000}; // "Define an array of size 2 of type long."
const double NOT_A_NUMBER = *( double* )lnNAN; // "Now, cast it to a double value!"
```

---

Of course, I’ve tested all of these and both representations elude to their respective numeric form (Denormalized, Indeterminate, Infinity & NaN) but the thing is:

### **What is happening in these non-standard representations?**

*More specifically, how is an array being converted to a number here and why are the values in said array specific to each numeric form?*

---

Here’s the code for each "special" number:

#### • Denormalized

```
/* Non-Standard Representation */
const unsigned long lnDEN[2] = {0x00000001, 0x00000000};
const double A_DENORMAL  = *( double* )lnDEN;

/* Standard Representation */
double dDEN = std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min();
```

#### • Indeterminate

```
/* Non-Standard Representation */
const unsigned long lnIND[2] = {0x00000000, 0xfff80000};
const double AN_INDETERMINATE  = *( double* )lnIND;

/* Standard Representation */
// ???
```

#### • Infinity

```
/* Non-Standard Representation */
const unsigned long lnINF[2] = {0x00000000, 0x7ff00000};
const double AN_INFINITY_POSITIVE  = *( double* )lnINF;

/* Standard Representation */
const double STD_AN_INFINITY_POSITIVE = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

#### • Not-A-Number (NaN)

```
/* Non-Standard Representation */
const unsigned long lnNAN[2] = {0x00000000, 0x7ff80000};
const double NOT_A_NUMBER = *( double* )lnNAN;

/* Standard Representation */
const double STD_NOT_A_NUMBERD = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

Comment: Everything here is undefined behavior. The forms are just what has been laid out in [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and they are very standard. It works because the values have the same bits. It's like `char a[2] = { 0xff, 0xff }; uint16_t b = *(uint16_t*)a; assert(b == 0xffff);`

Comment: @KamilCuk: I'm guessing that's where the "non-standard" is for.
I still want to understand why it works, though

Comment: It works because the bit patterns follow the bit patterns laid out by the IEEE 754 standard for a quiet NaN.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm also going to guess it's much the same for the other numeric forms i.e.: Infinity?

Comment: Pretty good guess.  Of course, the real picture is [a bit more complicated,](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/limits.html) which is why we rely on the standard libraries to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Note that denormals (aka subnormals) have multiple representations for different values, and there are two types of NaNs (signalling vs quiet/non-signalling) that also have multiple representations.

Comment: `*( double* )lnDEN` etc. is undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation)

Comment: @M.M: Yea, I'm currently aware (check the comments above), thanks.

Comment: Your “indeterminate” is simply `-nan`.